# ActionScript: programmatically adding children to a `mx:ViewStack`

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, addchild

I have a Flex `mx:ViewStack` that have some Flex children, but I want to add more using ActionScript.

```
var o:MyCanvas = new MyCanvas;
o.id = 'modRipley';
viewStack.addChild(o);
o = new MyCanvas;
o.id = 'modNewt';
viewStack.addChild(o);
o = new MyCanvas;
o.id = 'modGorman';
viewStack.addChild(o);
```

Stepping through, I don't see any increase to the `childDescriptors` member (nor the `_childDescriptors`) and:

```
viewStack.getChildByName('modNewt');
```

just returns null.

I am using the Flex 3.5 SDK.

Comment: addChild is correct, but I wouldn't expect childDescriptors to change, because that describes the mxml children. I also wouldn't expect getChildByName to work in your case because you haven't given the child a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of assigning `o.id = 'modNewt';` use `o.name = 'modNewt';` and try to access child by using `viewStack.getChildByName('modNewt');`. It should work.

Comment: I knew `id` was one of those hokey Flex things that couldn't be handled in a normal way in AS, but that's all I knew. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like my comment said, using `addChild` is correct, but your other code isn't useful. The `childDescriptors` is what the Flex framework uses to construct MXML children, so it's not expected to reflect dynamic changes made in ActionScript. And `getChildByName` requires that a child has a `name` value, while you have not given them a `name`, you've given them an `id`.

Typically, if I want to add view children dynamically, I do what the MXML compiler does with MXML children: create properties that will refer to the children when I create them. For example:

```
public class Example extends SomeMxmlComponentWithViewStack {
    public var myCanvas1:MyCanvas;
    public var myCanvas2:MyCanvas;
    public var myCanvas3:MyCanvas;

    override protected function createChildren():void {
        super.createChildren(); // creates the MXML children
        viewStack.addChild(myCanvas1 = new MyCanvas());
        viewStack.addChild(myCanvas2 = new MyCanvas());
        viewStack.addChild(myCanvas3 = new MyCanvas());
    }
}
```

Now from any code you can refer to `myCanvas1`, `myCanvas2` and `myCanvas3`. This is essentially what the MXML compiler does for you when you declare a component in MXML and give it an `id`.

Comment: +1 for the explanation about how to "properly" handle child instances in ActionScript. (they don't need to be public if you only need those references inside a component.)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I don't think this will work for me, because you seem to have the `MyCanvas`es created at the same time as the `ViewStack`. Several of the `ViewStack`'s children are being created at creation time, but my app needs to add and remove children through execution. (Come to think of it, I should probably figure out how to remove them as well)

Comment: Sure, you don't have to do it inside `createChildren` (that was just an example), you can create and remove whenever you want. The main point is that you have properties to refer to your children (ex `myCanvas1`, etc) so you don't lose track of them or need to use fragile lookup functions to find children.